# Shopify missing snippets and sections

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am using themekit and theme watch, but im my themes in Shopify some snippets and sections are not migrated. There are no error  in this files. If I create the file manually in Shopify theme it works.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question is too general. Please include any code you are trying to use to make it easier for the community to give advice.

Comment: theme watch uploads only those files that are created/modified and if they are in the proper folder structure. Recheck.

Comment: @HymnZzy  Theme kit can be a little more buggy than other development tools from my experience. theme watch will sometimes miss new snippets. The only way I have found to fix this issue is to copy the contents of the snippet, delete snippet and create new snippet and paste in contents - if your file structure is correct, it should now work. Be sure to check your file structure.